# Mojo::DOM: how does "matches" work?

Tags: html, perl, css-selectors, mojolicious

What do I need to change in the example below, so that the `matches( 'a[rel="next"]' )` returns `true`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Mojo::DOM;

my $content = '<html><body><div><a hello="world" rel="next">Next</a></div></body></html>';

my $bool_1 = $content =~ /<a.+?rel="next"/;
print "1 OK\n" if $bool_1;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( $content );
my $bool_2 = $dom->matches( 'a[rel="next"]' );
print "2 OK\n" if $bool_2; # does not print "2 OK"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `Mojo::DOM->new( $content )` is the entire DOM represented by the markup. The starting element is always the top-level element; in this case, it's `html`. Naturally, `html` does not match the selector `a[rel="next"]`, and therefore `matches()` returns false.

You need to navigate to the `a` element using [`at()`](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/DOM#at) before testing it:

```
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( $content );
my $a = $dom->at( 'a' );
my $bool_2;
if ( defined $a ) {
    $bool_2= $a->matches( 'a[rel="next"]' );
}
print "2 OK\n" if $bool_2;
```